# How do you resolve Polymer web components in Flask templates?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, polymer

How do you resolve Polymer web components in Flask templates? My first thought was to copy the component HTML to the templates directory, but then I realized they should be treated more like static files, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you should unpack them into the static folder then point to them as you usually would. Once you've unpacked them it should look like this (for each component you wish to load):

```
<link rel="import" href="/static/bower_components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html">
```